Expanding growth rate (linear stability analysis)
I have done a linear stability analysis for a system of coupled PDEs. The growth rate of perturbations, $\lambda$, satisfies an equation $f(\lambda)=0$. Now I want to find the leading order terms in the growth rate. I did two methods to find the growth rate as a function of the wavevector $q$.
First method: expanding $\lambda$ as $\lambda=\lambda_0+\lambda_1 q+\lambda_2 q^2+\lambda_3 q^3+\lambda_4 q^4$, and then subing the expansion in $f(\lambda)=0$ and solving $f(\lambda)=0$ for different powers of $q$.
Second method: Solving $f(\lambda)=0$ for $\lambda$, and then expanding $\lambda$ for different powers of $q$.
I expected the two methods to give the same result, but they did not!  I wonder why? And which method is correct.
I am asking this in the physics section because I don't understand where the difference comes from and what each method mean.
Here is the equation I tried to solve for $\lambda$.
$\lambda + D  q^2 + 2  a - 
  \frac{r  \: e  \:m}{6    J} + \lambda   \frac{(- r  \: e  \:m) q^2 (J - e)^2}{2(J^3   q^2  \lambda + 2  r  \: e  \:m)}
     =0$
in this equation $r<0$.

This is a mathematics question.

But there must be a physical meaning to it as well. What does each method mean and why are they different? @VincentThacker

@VincentThacker I edited the question

Can you write down $f(\lambda)$ explicitly? I'm having a hard time following what you did in terms of abstract notation. What is $\lambda$? Is $\lambda$ the growth rate? You said $f(\lambda)$ is the growth rate, but then I don't understand what $\lambda$ is or why you are solving for it.

could you add some details about the actual problem? Which equation is it? What kind of perturbation are you looking at? Could you list any ansatz you're doing?

@Andrew yes $\lambda$ is the growthrate. $f(\lambda)=0$ is the equation I need to solve to find the growth rate.

I have added $f(\lambda)$. @Andrew

I have added $f(\lambda)$. @basics
